# C++ sending keystrokes to another application

Tags: c++

I'm trying to send a F10 command to Chrome, but it is not working. This is what I have tried:

```
#include <windows.h>

void SendKeystrokesToChrome(HWND window, WORD key)
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wVk = key;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}

int main() {
    HWND chromeWindow = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("Google - Google Chrome"));

    if (chromeWindow != NULL) {
        SendKeystrokesToChrome(chromeWindow, VK_F12);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can get it to work by closing the app, but not sending keyboard shortcuts like f10.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is sending `VK_F12`, not F10.  Also, your function never uses the `window` value.  You're just sending the keystrokes to whichever application happens to have the focus (which is how `SendInput` works).

Comment: Although you might, ostensibly, be using C++, your code is not standard C++ (and standard C++ does not provide capabilities related to sending keystrokes).   The C++ tag is therefore off-topic.   Since you are using the windows API, you might consider using the winapi tag to increase your chances of getting a useful response.

Comment: On a side note: calling `SendInput()` with `cInputs=1` without any delays in between consecutive calls is a logic bug in your code.  You should be calling `SendInput()` with `cInputs=2` instead and give it an `INPUT[2]` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Roberts pointed me to a solution, so what i did was following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void SendKeystrokesToChrome(HWND window, WORD key)
{

    SetForegroundWindow(window);

    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wVk = key;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    // Key down
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

    // Key up
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}

int main() {
    HWND chromeWindow = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("Google - Google Chrome"));

    if (chromeWindow != NULL) {
        cout << "Active window found";
        SendKeystrokesToChrome(chromeWindow, VK_F5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do note that [`SetForegroundWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) has many restrictions, so you are not guaranteed to actually bring the window into the foreground.

Comment: That is completely true, though in my case it's good enough. but thanks for noticing :)